# Remove grid lines from java script plot

Tags: javascript, graph, plot, charts, nvd3.js

I have made a scatter chart based on the example found [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/blob/master/054-nvd3-line-chart-output/www/nvd3/examples/scatterChart.html).

I wish to remove the grid lines from the plot.

On [How do you remove the background gridlines in nvd3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469499/how-do-you-remove-the-background-gridlines-in-nvd3-js/28543632#28543632) I found a description I could use:

```
.tick {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

but I do not know where in the code to put it and I cannot make it work.

Thanks for any inputs :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line of CSS to your nv.d3.css file

```
 .nv-axis .tick line {
   display:none;
   }
```

This removes background grid-lines but keeps the details on the Y and X axis.

Comment: Great, worked thanks! How do you then enable the y-axis? How do you make it show a line as y-axis? And where is there documentation on this in general for plots? Thanks again :)

Comment: Documentation can be found here but it isn't extensive at all .. https://github.com/novus/nvd3/wiki/API-Documentation - If you test in the developer tools through google chrome, I'm sure you can find that out.